# Get Size of ApplicationWindow in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, applicationwindow

How do you get the size of the QML ApplicationWindow in C++?

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;

QObject *application_object = engine.rootObjects().first();

// Throws ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_11::height(int), no such signal
QObject::connect(application_object, SIGNAL(height(int)), &my_obj_here, SLOT(set_game_height(int)));
QObject::connect(application_object, SIGNAL(width(int)), &my_obj_here, SLOT(set_game_width(int)));

return app.exec();
```

I realize that I'm also not getting the size of the contents of the ApplicationWindow (minus the toolbar, menubar etc), but how do I get access to that?

Trying to access the `window` property on the `window_object` using the `property` method returns a null pointer.

Comment: what is `window_object`?

Comment: @eyllanesc, an artifact of copying and pasting out of my code. I updated the snippet to be more representative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `QQmlProperty` to obtain the `QQuickItem`, then connect with the signals `heightChanged` and `widthChanged`, these signals only notify that the property has changed but it does not indicate the value, so you must use the method `height()` and `width()`.

```
QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().first();
QQuickItem *contentItem =qvariant_cast<QQuickItem *>(QQmlProperty::read(topLevel, "contentItem"));
if(contentItem){
    QObject::connect(contentItem, &QQuickItem::heightChanged,
                     [&my_obj_here, contentItem](){
        my_obj_here.set_game_height(contentItem->height());
    });
    QObject::connect(contentItem, &QQuickItem::widthChanged, 
                     [&my_obj_here, contentItem](){
        my_obj_here.set_game_width(contentItem->width());
    });
}
```

Another solution is to make the connection on the `QML` side, for this you must create the `q-property`:

```
class GameObject: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int game_width READ game_width WRITE set_game_width NOTIFY game_widthChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int game_height READ game_height WRITE set_game_height NOTIFY game_heightChanged)
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    int game_width() const{
        return m_width;
    }
    void set_game_width(int width){

        if(width == m_width)
            return;
        m_width = width;
        emit game_widthChanged();
    }
    int game_height() const{
        return m_height;
    }
    void set_game_height(int height){
        if(height == m_height)
            return;
        m_height = height;
        emit game_heightChanged();
    }
signals:
    void game_widthChanged();
    void game_heightChanged();
private:
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
...
GameObject my_obj_here;

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("my_obj_here", &my_obj_here);
...
```

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow{


    Connections{
        target: contentItem
        onHeightChanged:
            my_obj_here.game_height = height
        onWidthChanged:
            my_obj_here.game_width = width
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Any reason to use qvariant_cast instead using the`QVariant::value` method? I feel like the `value` method is more readable, but I'm wondering if that's because I'm just not use to casting, and wanted to get an outside opinion.

Comment: @BenHoff they are equivalent, it is a matter of taste :)